# replacing special characters in first column only in r

Tags: r, replace

Hi I have a text file in this format:

```
            x  
M.00116    952 
M.00046  41483 
M.00033      4
```

I need to replace the "." with an "_" in r. But for  I am not able to do it by using this :

```
sub("\\.", "_", c)
```

I get this output

```
c(952, 41483, 4)
```

I need an out put like :

```
x  
M-00116    952 
M-00046  41483 
M-00033      4
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `chartr` from `base R`

```
chartr('.', '-', x)
#[1] "M-00116 952 M-00046 41483 M-00033 4"
```

#### data

```
x <- "M.00116 952 M.00046 41483 M.00033 4"
```

Comment: tried this as well, but does not seem to work. My data frame c is in two columns. First column has no header and has "M.XXXX" and second column is a number. sorry for the typo in my original post, the "x" is the header for col 2 not col 1. Maybe that is why?  I can paste a header to my first column and force it to do it, but I don't want to do that unnecessary step! can't see what is troubling here, should be quite simple!

Comment: @user2635253  Looks like it is `rownames.`  try `row.names(yourdata) <- chartr('.', '-', row.names(yourdata))`

Comment: Awesome! That did it! I was looking at it as a col of M.XXXX I should have looked at it as row names. Thanks so much for your help! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x <- "M.00116 952 M.00046 41483 M.00033 4"
gsub("\\.", "-", x)
```

EDIT:

Replace "sub" with `gsub`:

```
gsub("\\.", "_", data$colname)
```

EDIT:

This worked for me:

```
c <- c("M.00116", "M.00046", "M.00033") 
x <- c("952", "41483", "4")

d <- cbind(c, x)

colnames(d)[2] <- ""

gsub("\\.", "_", d)

     c                
[1,] "M_00116" "952"  
[2,] "M_00046" "41483"
[3,] "M_00033" "4"
```

Comment: I have it this way:                                                                                                   > head(c)
             x
    M.00116   952  
    M.00046 41483  
    M.00033     4  
    M.00142     0  
    M.00048     0  
    M.00113 30347  I need to replace the "." only in my first column not my second

Comment: Are you specifying the column name or using `sub` over the whole data frame?

Comment: tried did not work like the way I want it:  I get this output  > gsub("\\.", "-", c)
[1] "c(952, 41483, 4)  does not do it

Comment: Change it to: `gsub("\\.", "-", data$column_name) `

Comment: I am using it over the whole data frame. the first column has no column name

Comment: first column has no col name and I want this to happen in the first column. second column is just counts.

Comment: I edited my post with what worked for me. What is the structure of the data, `str(data)`